# I am having problems installing NLTK

Tags: python, windows, installation, package, nltk

Its been ages since I've tried to run Python without eclipse, but for this I just want to run it through command line, but I still need to install the module, which I can't remember how to do.

Problem is the answer to "how to install a module is somehow not answered succinctly" anywhere I can find.

I have the folder python34 in my C drive.

I have the folder with NLTK in it. Running setup.py in the NLTK window opens and closes a python window instantly.

Trying to import NLTK results in a package not found error.

I feel like an idiot, what am I missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Comment: I know how to do it with Anaconda, but I would like to do it just in the command line. This is possible right? I'm just missing something simple.